# Is this still considered $\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following solution to the matrix a zero subspace? (Assume that the last column of zeros is the constant portion of the matrix)

I'm working on some kernel problems, and if a linear transformation is one-to-one or not, I have to see if the kernel of the transformation is the zero subspace or not.

A=$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

(If anything I said is unclear, assume that the first column is $x$ and second column is $y$ and third column is for constants. The first row says $x=0$, the second row says $y=0
$)

Comment: What does the third row represent? An augmented matrix with two variables would have two rows and three columns, not three rows and three columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This matrix is of rank $2$, which by the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra) means that the kernel is a $3-2=1$ dimensional subspace, so it cannot be the 0 vector.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\
0 \\
0\end{bmatrix}$$

You are correct that $x=0$ and $y=0$, but what about $z$?